# Issue with device orientation and UIView during startup

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiview, uiinterfaceorientation

I'm working on a project in which when the user press a button a video will be played, I have to program this app for all orientations. I have added images as background for buttons given those buttons position based on the size of the superview like this:

```
button1.frame = CGRectMake(0.15 * (self.view.frame.size.width),0.15 * (self.view.frame.size.height), 0.2 * (self.view.frame.size.width), 0.2 * (self.view.frame.size.height));
```

When I start the app in portrait it's view is fine and also when I rotate it works fine :

[image: screenshot portrait]

But if I start my app in landscape it shows a view like this:

[image: screenshot landscape]

I'v used a lot of code to resize views and subviews:

```
-(void) viewDidLoad
{

...
self.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin |
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin |
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;

[self.view setAutoresizesSubviews:YES];

button1.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin |
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin |
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
...

}
```

and in didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation() and willRotateToInterfaceOrientation():

```
...
    self.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin |
        UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin |
        UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;

    [self.view setAutoresizesSubviews:YES];

    button1.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin |
        UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin |
        UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
    ...
```

I'v also specified YES for return in shouldAutoRotate(). What am I lacking here? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Get rid of this older approach and take the advantage of Autolayout. Things will be easier for you.

Comment: Ya thank you, but I'm programming for IOS 5.0 and also I can't disobey my orders, not to use .xib files or storyboard.

Answer (score 1):

```
 you have to declaration below and all give them in viewDidLoad but frame give in
 this code  


-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
 {

   [self willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation duration:1.0];

   UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;

   if(orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft)
   {
     [self setFrameForLeftAndRightOrientation];
   }
   else if(orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait )
   {
     [self setFrameForPortraitAndUpsideDownOrientation];
   }
 }

  - (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:
    (UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
      duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
    {
            if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || 
            toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
           {
             [self setFrameForLeftAndRightOrientation];
           }
           else if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
           {
             [self setFrameForPortraitAndUpsideDownOrientation];
           }
    }

-(void)setFrameForLeftAndRightOrientation
{
     if(IS_IPAD)
     {

     }
     else if(IS_IPHONE)
     {

        if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568)
       {


       }
       else
      {

      }
    }

}

 -(void)setFrameForPortraitAndUpsideDownOrientation
 {
   if(IS_IPAD)
    {

     }
    else if(IS_IPHONE)
    {


    if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568)
    {


    }
    else
    {

    }
}

}
```